# Need to download KB2919335 standalone package but Microsoft Site doesn't give the actual link

Tags: download, updates

I'm having USB3.0 Drive suspend issues like the ones that are documented [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2013/11/01/help-after-installing-windows-8-1-my-usb-drive-disappears-or-file-transfers-stop-unexpectedly-r-a-post-title.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) and would like to try installing KB2919355 to fix the issue. But when trying to download the standalone package, I just get stuck in a loop, the download doesn't start because there's no actual file download link available, and clicking the usual 'click here if file doesn't start after given time' link just sends me back to the file selection page, instead of giving a working download link.

What to do? Thanks!

Comment: running 8.1 Pro x64, not that it matters - the issue is with the download link and MS page I think

Comment: [This link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42335) works for me. (Click the Download button, select the files you want.)

Comment: These KB's must be installed in the following order: clearcompressionflag.exe, KB2919355, KB2932046, KB2959977, KB2937592, KB2938439, and KB2934018..... KB2919442 is a prerequisite for Windows 8.1 Update and should be installed before attempting to install KB2919355